# Configuring and adding images/links/URLS into pop-ups on ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-online, configuration, administration

I am administering an ArcGIS Online Organizational account and am newer to this side of ArcGIS Online.

I am trying to create a map with pop-ups that contain different images for different points, attachments (such as reports) and URLs.

The Help section on ArcGIS unfortunately did not provide me much insight as to how to go about this.

Is anyone able to assist me?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [this](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm) section on their website?

It's pretty straightforward.

[image]

Then you can configure it from there and customize them as you wish by clicking on the arrow next to the feature in the map viewer and selecting "configure pop-up".

[image]

If you're up for it, the ESRI Javascript APIs have a lot of functionality you can play with.